# Find all combinations with repetition of elements

Tags: combinatorics

A set of n elements is given. Now one selects k elements. Then there are $n^k=m$, $k$-combinations. To get all possible combinations one can transform m of base 10 to m of base n. Then subtract m by one and transform (m-1) of base 10 to base n. Now we repeat this for $m > 0$. As a result we have strings of base $n$. If one stores the digits of all these string in a list and remove from each of these lists the first element, we have all possible combinations of $n$ over $k$ elements.

Example:
Let $n=2$ and $k=2$, then there are $4$ combinations. This yields at first the digit list $(1,0,0)$. The next list is the digit string for $(4-1)$ of base $2$. The result is $(0,1,1)$. Then, the last to lists are $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$, corresponding to $2$ and $1$ respectively. Next we remove the first elements of all lists and get $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. These four lists represent all possible combinations.

Is there a name for this algorithm?

Comment: If you use the numbers from $0$ to $n^k-1$ instead, you don't even need to delete the first element.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the [$n$-ary Gray code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#n-ary_Gray_code). Not only does this enumerate all such sequences, it only changes one digit at a time, making it efficient for many uses.